# Humorous sci-fi book with a quirky space captain where everyone is turning into "glass"

Tags: story-identification, novel

I posted this question on another website, but I've yet to find the name of the book. I remember some very specific details, but nothing I can type into a search engine (I've tried).

Here are the details I remember:

- The book might be part of a series of books that follow this quirky space captain.
- It takes place in universe where people are in contact with many types aliens
- The story begins with an entire "council" of thin bird like aliens turning into glass, this has something to do with some "virus" or "disease" related to entropy some how, and the fact that the silica they turn into is the lowest entropy state.
- The story follows an alien that can shoot spines out of his back at some point. There is some romantic relationships between him and a human woman. She dies by turning into glass and he gets arrested, sent to some prison ship and mutilated so that he can't shoot spines anymore.
- All the while, the space captain is going on quirky adventurous trying to solve the whole mystery about why people are turning into glass. Also, at some point he visits a "graveyard" ship full of dead aliens, which is being overseen by another alien that gives him a tour around.
- Lastly, the book was most likely published between 1999-2007, although I'm not 100% sure (it was definitely modern, though).

I don't remember how it was resolved. I think it was found out that it was some sort of post-physical or extra-dimensional being that was stealing energy from out universe, which was turning living entities into glass.

Comment: A note:  I don't remember how it was resolved. I think it was found out that it was some sort of post-physical or extra-dimensional being that was stealing energy from out universe, which was turning living entities into glass.

Comment: This sort of sounds like _Expendable_  series by James Alan Gardner; it features a race of people made out of glass that eventually stop moving; you find the answer later in the series. If this is right; I'll turn it into a formal answer.

Comment: @djm strangely enough, another person made this suggestion on another website I where I posted this. Unfortunately it's not that story. Thank you for helping, though!

Comment: You might also want to mention the stories you've discounted here; https://www.reddit.com/r/printSF/comments/2tacnw/forgot_the_title_of_humorous_sci_fi_book_with_a/

Comment: [According to this user's Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/printSF/comments/2tacnw/forgot_the_title_of_humorous_sci_fi_book_with_a/), it is not by Ijon Tichy, it is not *Expendable* by James Alan Gardner, it is not *Space Mercenaries* by A. Bertram Chandler, it is not *The Crystal World* by JG Ballard, and it is not *Glass* by Stephen Palmer.